# Argument of type 'DependencyList | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my project, using an image crop section for that purpose I refer to the following code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-crop-demo-with-react-hooks-forked-67vcek?file=/src/useDebounceEffect.ts:0-316.

When I use the files with the same file structure in the above path it shows the following errors too.

[image]

error

```
ERROR in src/imagePreview.ts:8:19

TS2345: Argument of type '(value: Blob | PromiseLike<Blob>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobCallback'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'blob' are incompatible.
    Type 'Blob | null' is not assignable to type 'Blob | PromiseLike<Blob>'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Blob | PromiseLike<Blob>'.
     6 | function toBlob(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement): Promise<Blob> {
     7 |   return new Promise((resolve) => {
  >  8 |     canvas.toBlob(resolve)
       |                   ^^^^^^^
     9 |   })
    10 | }
    11 |


ERROR in src/useDebounceEffect.ts:10:27

TS2345: Argument of type 'DependencyList | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '[]'.
     8 |   useEffect(() => {
     9 |     const t = setTimeout(() => {
  > 10 |       fn.apply(undefined, deps)
       |                           ^^^^
    11 |     }, waitTime)
    12 |
    13 |     return () => {
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'

import ReactCrop, {
  centerCrop,
  makeAspectCrop,
  Crop,
  PixelCrop,
} from 'react-image-crop'
import { canvasPreview } from './canvasPreview'
import { useDebounceEffect } from './useDebounceEffect'

import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css'

// This is to demonstate how to make and center a % aspect crop
// which is a bit trickier so we use some helper functions.
function centerAspectCrop(
  mediaWidth: number,
  mediaHeight: number,
  aspect: number,
) {
  return centerCrop(
    makeAspectCrop(
      {
        unit: '%',
        width: 90,
      },
      aspect,
      mediaWidth,
      mediaHeight,
    ),
    mediaWidth,
    mediaHeight,
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState('')
  const previewCanvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)
  const imgRef = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null)
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState<Crop>()
  const [completedCrop, setCompletedCrop] = useState<PixelCrop>()
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1)
  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(0)
  const [aspect, setAspect] = useState<number | undefined>(16 / 9)

  function onSelectFile(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      setCrop(undefined) // Makes crop preview update between images.
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.addEventListener('load', () =>
        setImgSrc(reader.result.toString() || ''),
      )
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
    }
  }

  function onImageLoad(e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLImageElement>) {
    if (aspect) {
      const { width, height } = e.currentTarget
      setCrop(centerAspectCrop(width, height, aspect))
    }
  }

  useDebounceEffect(
    async () => {
      if (
        completedCrop?.width &&
        completedCrop?.height &&
        imgRef.current &&
        previewCanvasRef.current
      ) {
        // We use canvasPreview as it's much faster than imgPreview.
        canvasPreview(
          imgRef.current,
          previewCanvasRef.current,
          completedCrop,
          scale,
          rotate,
        )
      }
    },
    100,
    [completedCrop, scale, rotate],
  )

  function handleToggleAspectClick() {
    if (aspect) {
      setAspect(undefined)
    } else if (imgRef.current) {
      const { width, height } = imgRef.current
      setAspect(16 / 9)
      setCrop(centerAspectCrop(width, height, 16 / 9))
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Crop-Controls">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={onSelectFile} />
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="scale-input">Scale: </label>
          <input
            id="scale-input"
            type="number"
            step="0.1"
            value={scale}
            disabled={!imgSrc}
            onChange={(e) => setScale(Number(e.target.value))}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="rotate-input">Rotate: </label>
          <input
            id="rotate-input"
            type="number"
            value={rotate}
            disabled={!imgSrc}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setRotate(Math.min(180, Math.max(-180, Number(e.target.value))))
            }
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleToggleAspectClick}>
            Toggle aspect {aspect ? 'off' : 'on'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {Boolean(imgSrc) && (
        <ReactCrop
          crop={crop}
          onChange={(_, percentCrop) => setCrop(percentCrop)}
          onComplete={(c) => setCompletedCrop(c)}
          aspect={aspect}
        >
          <img
            ref={imgRef}
            alt="Crop me"
            src={imgSrc}
            style={{ transform: `scale(${scale}) rotate(${rotate}deg)` }}
            onLoad={onImageLoad}
          />
        </ReactCrop>
      )}
      <div>
        {Boolean(completedCrop) && (
          <canvas
            ref={previewCanvasRef}
            style={{
              border: '1px solid black',
              objectFit: 'contain',
              width: completedCrop.width,
              height: completedCrop.height,
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

imagePreview.ts

```
import { PixelCrop } from 'react-image-crop'
import { canvasPreview } from './canvasPreview'

let previewUrl = ''

function toBlob(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement): Promise<Blob> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    canvas.toBlob(resolve)
  })
}

// Returns an image source you should set to state and pass
// `{previewSrc && <img alt="Crop preview" src={previewSrc} />}`
export async function imgPreview(
  image: HTMLImageElement,
  crop: PixelCrop,
  scale = 1,
  rotate = 0,
) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvasPreview(image, canvas, crop, scale, rotate)

  const blob = await toBlob(canvas)
  if (previewUrl) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(previewUrl)
  }

  previewUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  return previewUrl
}
```

useDebounceEffect.ts

```
import { useEffect, DependencyList } from 'react'

export function useDebounceEffect(
  fn: () => void,
  waitTime: number,
  deps?: DependencyList,
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const t = setTimeout(() => {
      fn.apply(undefined, deps)
    }, waitTime)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(t)
    }
  }, deps)
}
```

Please give me some suggestions to fix this problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Additionally it should not depend on external content behind links. [Edit] your question to include the code and error message as text instead.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Question edited and included the errors.